# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable - when trying to create csv files

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, int, typeerror

My dictionary `auto_anno` looks like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {'Beda': {'Fuery': {'anger': 2,
                                'anticipation': 1,
                                'disgust': 2,
                                'fear': 2,
                                'sadness': 2}},
             'Fuery': {'Beda': {'surprise': 1},
                       'Fuery': {'anger': 1,
                                 'anticipation': 6,
                                 'disgust': 2,
                                 'fear': 1,
                                 'joy': 5,
                                 'sadness': 2,
                                 'surprise': 4,
                                 'trust': 4},
                       'Hawkeye': {'anger': 1, 'fear': 3, 'trust': 1},...#etc
```

My goal is to automatically create two csv files using these kind of dictionaries. One csv file for nodes (Character's Ids from 0 to x, and their Label, aka the character's name), and the second csv file for their relations according to an emotion and its weight (here: keys of first dict are the the `source`, and the keys of the nested dict are the `target`.

So far I came up with this function that uses `pickle` to load the dictionary above:

```
def automate_gephi():
    """CREATES TWO CSV FILES TO USE IN GEPHI"""
    auto_anno = pickle.load(open("auto_anno.p", "rb"))
    characters = set()
    for char1,value in auto_anno.items(): # this is the predicted graph (a dictionary where each key is an experiencer and each value is a stimulus with emotions)
        for char2,val in value.items():
            characters.add(char1)
            characters.add(char2)

    file_node = open("nodes.csv", "w") #only nodes and id's go here
    file_node.write("Id"+"\t"+"Label"+"\n")

    # for each node create a numeric id and write to file
    for n,name in enumerate(characters):
        file_node.write(str(n)+"\t"+"%s" %name+"\n")
    file_node.close()

    # edges
    read_nodes = open("nodes.csv","r")
    edges_file = open("edges.csv","w")
    sep = "\t"
    edges_file.write("Source"+sep+"Target"+sep+"Label"+sep+"Weight"+"\n")
    Adjacency = {}

    for line in read_nodes:
        try:
            Adjacency[line.strip().split("\t")[1]] = line.strip().split("\t")[0]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        continue

    for key,value in auto_anno.items():
        source = key
        for k1,v1 in value.items():
            target = k1
            for emotion,weight in v1.items():
                try:
                    edges_file.write(str(Adjacency[source])+sep+str\
                                     (Adjacency[target])+sep+emotion+sep+\
                                     " ".join([i for i in weight["Weight"]])+"\n")
                except KeyError:
                    pass
    edges_file.close()
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
line 224, in automate_gephi
    " ".join([i for i in weight["Weight"]])+"\n")

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

An example of the desired output:

**FILE 1: Nodes**:

```
Id  Label
0   Beda
1   Fuery
2   Hawkeye
```

**FILE 2: Edges**:

```
Source  Target  Label  Weight
0  1  anger  2
0  1  anticipation  1
.
.
.#etc
```

What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seem that `weight` is not an iterable object, but an integer. If you not sure try to add print line `for emotion,weight in v1.items(): print(emotion, weight)`

Comment: I did that, and it outputs what I'm asking for: `anger 2
anticipation 1
disgust 2
fear 2
sadness 2....#etc`
- I am trying to add those results to the last two columns `Label` and `Weight`

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
for emotion,weight in v1.items()
```

You set `emotion` to the key and `weight` to the value. Later you try this `weight["Weight"]` which is giving you that error as `weight` is just a number at this point. You need to modify your list comprehension, which I/we can help with, but i'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do with it.

Comment: I'm trying to output the `weight`, which is the number of occurances of the basic emotions (their keys of the nested dicts) to the column `Weight` as I stated in the example **FILE 2: Edges**. There it's the `2`and `1` at the last column. I hope this clarifies it...

Comment: It looks like you can replace `[i for i in weight["Weight"]]` with just `weight`. Your `for` loop should already iterate over all the emotion-weight pairs so you don't need list comprehension.